# how to write to a text file in C# in Linux with MONO Develop

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, monodevelop

Im using Ubunto OS with MONO Develop and Im programming with C#.

I want to write into a text file but I dont sure how to do it.

I tried this:

```
string[] lines = {"some text1", "some text2", "some text3"};
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"/home/myuser/someText.txt", lines);
```

this didn't work.

I tried this:

```
string str = "some text";

StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter("/home/myuser/someText.txt");

a.Write(str);
```

this didn't work too.

what to do?

tnx.

Comment: I didn't get an error message. Its continue to runnig but dont write to the file. I assume my way to write to a text file is somehow wrong.  so I want to know how to do this write.

Comment: Did you closed or flushed the file after writting in it?

Comment: Your method is ok. Something else is wrong. You already know `how to do this write`

Comment: @Amedio: that doesn't apply to the WriteAllLines case

Comment: The first method should work. Second method you forgot to close the stream...

Answer (score 7):

Both should work, perhaps you forgot to provide the application code?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
         string[] lines = {"some text1", "some text2", "some text3"};
         File.WriteAllLines(@"/home/myuser/someText.txt", lines);
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile with `dmcs program.cs`, e.g.

Comment: this not the problem. mybe in linux I should do this in a diffrent way but I dont know

Comment: This _is_ on linux, my friend. By the way, have you tried running your first two lines in [`csharp` (Mono's Interactive Shell)](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl)? You can easily see it works (unless, e.g. the directory is missing or you don't have permission)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you close the stream (File.Close() or a.Close(), I'm not familiar with c# syntax) as only when the stream is disposed, it actually writes on the file.